# AzureDevops - PR Trigger - PR status remains in "In progress" state

Tags: triggers, azure-devops, pull-request

We have Pull Request triggers enabled for our release and the all the automatic stages are already completed. But still, the Pull request status is shown as in progress. We have branch policies and pull request triggers properly set.

**Note** - There are few stages with manual deployment, followed by stages with PR triggers enabled. Is this causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

PR status is overall status of release. In case of Multiple stages, if any of the stage is in 'in-progress' state, status will be 'in-progress'. Status takes into account all the stages for which "Pull request deployment" option is enabled. In your case since there are stages with Pull request deployment enabled and are not started (as preceeding stage is manual) status will be 'in-progress'. If you don't want those stages for PR validation, Please disable the option for those stages. Then status computation will not consider those stages.